# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index when use Pandas Fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

> Update : It seems due to .loc ,if i uses the original df from
> pd.read_excel, it is fine.

I have a dataframe with Dtypes as follows.

This is csv for the dataframe :
[CSV File](https://khoavanhoceduvn-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/7418_elibrary_su/ERNZ8ilj6ftIpWUMkp-utz4BWvqiROZ9LJ9TD3IQyzUHXw?e=fJXHId)

Date        datetime64[ns]
Amout             float64
Currency            object
ID                  object

[image]
[image]

I used the following code to replace NaT, NaN

```
a=np.datetime64('2000-01-01')
values={'Date':a,'Amount':0,'Currency':'0','ID':'0'}
df.fillna(value=values,inplace=True)
```

However, I got the error : TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

I also tried to fillna with each column and I saw no error message but the Nan and Nat still remain unchanged.

```
a=np.datetime64('2000-01-01')
df[['Date']].fillna(a,inplace=True)
df[['Amount']].fillna(0,inplace=True)
df[['Currency']].fillna('0',inplace=True)
df[['ID']].fillna('0',inplace=True)
```

It seems very strange to me since I have use fillna successfully many times.
Please give me an advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can  you give sample csv as text format instead of image?

Comment: I have just added the link to csv file on the top of my post.

Comment: I tried reading your csv but i can't reproduce error. At my side it is working as expected with your code - `df.fillna(value=values,inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

I think there are strings `NaN` in `Currency` and `Id` columns, so use:

```
df = df.replace({'Currency': {'NaN': '0'}, 'ID':{'NaN': '0'}})
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try your way. But I still wonder why it threw error message when I tried the first method.

Comment: I have tried and it did not work. I have just added the link to csv file on the top of my post. Can you have a look at it?